# LC.exe could not be run

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

On compilation I receive error for [LC.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha0k3c9f(v=vs.80).aspx)

`The specified task executable "LC.exe" could not be run. The filename or extension is too long`

This error occurs when I compile my unit test project.  Of the google tricks I've seen, nothing has worked.

- I am set to Target framework = ".NET Framework 4" not client profile.

This started today.  There's hardly anything in source control history.  The changes all have to do with `AssemblyInfo.cs` where a 3rd party utility increments our version #'s.

**UPDATE**
Looking out my output window the command line call to LC.EXE is **HUGE**

CompileLicxFiles:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\LC.exe /target:BuildAll.Tests.dll /complist:Properties\licenses.licx /outdir:obj\Debug\ /i:C:\`

There's 100's of `/i` params...

Comment: What is `LC.exe` and why is it running on compilation?

Comment: I think LC.exe is used for license project when they don't want publish in community. In fact, it will embedded public key in assembly and only other company having a private key can use it @jrummell

Comment: I'm getting the same error.  It appears that I have too many References in my project.  When I added "Microsoft.Sharepoint" it blew up.  When I removed that reference, it compiled again.

Comment: None of these answers seem to give a real solution. They only seem to be short term workarounds. For projects with very large numbers of references (including indirect references), the problem will still occur. MSFT needs a scalable solution to the problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is MS Support workaround:

> when you build the project , delete the Licence file from the project
>   everytime you get this error , just delete the licence file

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779433/lc-exe-task-command-line-too-long

Comment: Deleting licx file makes my exe unlicensed

Answer (score 17):

I changed the value of the property `Build Action` from `EmbeddedResource` to `None` on the file `licenses.licx`. It solved the problem.

Comment: Don't know if it worked for OP, but for me it worked. I guess if it worked for OP as well it should be marked as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2):

had same problem. 
For the Lc.exe a command line is generated this is limitied up to around 32k chars.
In this command normally all references are written with theit fullpath.

so if you have many references you can get into trouble.

There are some things you can do:
 - Remove unused references
 - Make sure that you don't reference indirect depdencies. Use instead the hint path you can define for the assemblies.
 - Shorten the path in with the references are placed
 - You could create a virtual drive to put the refs there to get the shorted possible reference path (eg. Z:\my.dll)

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem today, and it got resolved when I changed the path of the reference to a less longer path. For example, I initially put it in `mydocuments\user\...\...\..`. But when I changed the path to `c:\dlls\`, it worked like a charm. Hope that helps.

Comment: Was your initial path fully resolved (i.e., `C:\path\to\mydocuments\user\...`)?

Answer (score 0):

I had a bad problem with the file LC.exe, everything was due to the fact that the components I used were in a network drive (G :) and from that position I could never compile the executable. 
I finally solved by adding the IP address of the network drive between sites intranet reliable in the internet options.

Answer (score 0):

I used the command-line utility "Subst" as mentioned in this blog [post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/02/15/if-your-build-fails-with-msb6002-the-command-line-for-the-resgen-task-is-too-long/) to resolve my issue with LC.exe.

1. Turn on Normal or higher Verbosity for your build.
2. In the Output window, examine the line where the LC task is being executed. Notice there will be many /i parameters with paths to other binaries.
3. Find one or more paths that you can use "Subst" to help shorten the path to help reduce the total length of all parameters passed to "LC.exe".
4. Next, open the problem project's properties window in Visual Studio and select the References tab and then add the new drives you defined with Subst.

Build the project.

Remember, Subst does not persist through reboot.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Link as answers are best for comments not answers. I suggest editing the above answer to add the main parts so its in one place.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I added this code into my project and it worked.

```
<Target Name="WorkaroundMSBuild2836" BeforeTargets="CompileLicxFiles">
   <!-- Work around https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2836 by
        temporarily setting TargetFrameworkVersion to a version high
        high enough to cause the LC task to use a response file. -->
   <PropertyGroup>
      <_OriginalTargetFrameworkVersion>$(TargetFrameworkVersion) 
      </_OriginalTargetFrameworkVersion>
      <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
   </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
<Target Name="UndoWorkaroundMSBuild2836" AfterTargets="CompileLicxFiles">
   <PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFrameworkVersion>$(_OriginalTargetFrameworkVersion) 
   </TargetFrameworkVersion>
   </PropertyGroup>
 </Target>
```

For further information read [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/291229/lcexe-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long-1.html)